# Custom message is not displayed in Azure Java Function App

Tags: java, azure, maven, azure-functions

I have created a Java function in Azure from the az cli and the function app is getting deployed,however when I access the Function App url I cannot see the custom message in the message body.

Below are the steps followed:
1.Wrote a custom java program LogFile.java to read data from a .log file
2.Ran the command to generate the Functions project from a Maven archetype i.e. mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=com.microsoft.azure -DarchetypeArtifactId=azure-functions-archetype -DjavaVersion=8

3.Copied the LogFile.java file in Function project directory: /test/logfile-functions/src/main/java/com/logfile
4.Edited Function.java code to display the messages from log file for eg:

LogFile log = new LogFile()

return request.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.OK).body("Log File messages : " + log.ReadLogData()).build();

5.Ran mvn clean package command to build the project and package the JAR file into the target directory
6.Deployed the function project to a new function app in Azure portal using mvn azure-functions:deploy

The function app is getting deployed in Azure but when I access the function app URL , the request body displays only **Log File messages :**  instead of **Log File messages : & the  messages from log file.**

But the log data is getting printed in the step while building the code.
context.getLogger().info("Log File messages :  "+ log.ReadLogData());

Please help me with this query

Answer (score 0):

Tried with `log4j2`, but logs don't come up in invocations details and hence they don't show up in Application Insights query either.

But `Log4j2` logs appear under "Log stream" section of any of your Functions Apps. But again, that's not really helpful.

If you have already built-in application with some other logging framework, then either you need to change all of your logging to `java.util.logging` or do below.

Create below 2 custom classes in a separate maven module and include that to all of your function modules. Have same package name as the framework that you are using. In my case its "org.apache.logging.log4j"

They are not perfectly built custom classes. But this works.

**LogManager.java**

```
package org.apache.logging.log4j;

public class LogManager {
static Logger logger = new Logger();

public static Logger getLogger() {
    return logger;
}

public static void setLogger(Logger logger1) {
    logger = logger1;
}

public static Logger getLogger(Class<?> class1) {
    return logger;
}

public static Logger getLogger(String name) {
    return logger;
}
```

**Logger.java**

```
package org.apache.logging.log4j;

import java.util.logging.Level;

public class Logger {
private java.util.logging.Logger logger;

public void setLogger(java.util.logging.Logger logger) {
    this.logger = logger;
}

public void debug(Object... obj) {
    printLog(obj, Level.FINE);
}

public void info(Object... obj) {
    printLog(obj, Level.INFO);
}

public void error(Object... obj) {
    printLog(obj, Level.SEVERE);
}

public void log(Object level, Object... obj) {
    printLog(obj, Level.FINEST);
}

public void warn(Object... obj) {
    printLog(obj, Level.WARNING);
}

private void printLog(Object[] obj, Level level) {
    if (obj != null) {

        String logString = obj[0] != null ? obj[0].toString() : "";

        if (obj.length > 1) {
            for (int i = 1; i < obj.length; i++) {
                if (obj[i] != null) {
                    logString = logString.replaceFirst("\\{}", obj[i].toString());
                }
            }                   
        }
        logger.log(level, logString);
    }
}
}
```

Then you can set your custom logger using Azure's Execution Context.

```
// LOG var Global to class    
private final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger(BgdInfoAnalyticsHandler.class);

@FunctionName("func-name-fn")
    public void run(
            @ServiceBusQueueTrigger(name = "TriggerName", queueName = "sbq-use-queue-name", connection = "AzureWebJobsServiceBus") String input,
            ExecutionContext context) {
        LOG.setLogger(context.getLogger());
        LogManager.setLogger(LOG);
        String fnInput = HostServiceUtil.getBlobData(input);
        LOG.info("fnInput : {} ", fnInput);
        invokeService(fnInput);
    }
```

Once this Logger is initiated/set in the entry point of your run method with Azure's ExecutionContext logger. You get this logger from any other class by doing LogManager.getLogger (Custom Class) as it is static.

**Note:** Static vars are being shared by different invocations or functions (if they resides in same function app)

Then you can do query in Application Insights as below:

```
union traces
| union exceptions | union requests
// | where timestamp > ago(2d)
// | where cloud_RoleName =~ 'fun-use-function-app-name' and operation_Name =~ 'function-name-fn' //and operation_Id =~ "7303edd79433b0468f934c80a88e5f77"
// | where innermostMessage contains "Exception" or message contains "Exception"
| project timestamp, message = iff(message != '', message, 
    iff(innermostMessage != '', innermostMessage, customDimensions.['prop__{OriginalFormat}'])), logLevel = customDimensions.['LogLevel']
    , operation_Name, operation_Id, cloud_RoleName, invocationId=customDimensions['InvocationId']
| order by timestamp asc
| take 3000
```

You can also see Failure/Exception under: ApplicationInsights > Investigate section > Failures